# Dividing big data into time slices and storing in different json files

Tags: python, json, mongodb, time-series, tweets

I have 10GBs of tweets data in mongodb as well as in json file I need to divide these tweets into time slices and store separately in different json files. Which is the best solution for such a big data.?
I have tried using sort in mongo query and tried using bounds from pymongo code nothing works since its a huge file.

I have tried sorting the whole file giving the query like this to divide into hourly tweets..

```
{
    'timestamp': {
        '$lt': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 59, 59),
        '$gte': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 0, 0)
     }
}
```

but it always returns zero result in python. So I tried directly in mongo shell, but it is throwing a memory error since it's a large dataset. So what would be the solution for filtering it out?

Comment: You need to add more detail if you want this question to gain more traction. What exactly have you tried, and how exactly did it fail?

Comment: I have tried sorting the whole file giving the query like this to divide into hourly tweets.. {'timestamp': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 59, 59), '$gte': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 0, 0)}} but it always returns zero result in python. so i tried directly in mongo shell it is throwing memory error since its a large dataset. So what would be the solution for filtering it out?

Comment: Add that information *to the question itself*, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the mongodb aggregation framework for that. I suggest you something like that:

```
db.tweets.aggregate([
{$group:{
    _id:{ 'year':{$year:'$timestamp'},
          'month':{$month:'$timestamp'},
          'day':{$dayOfMonth:'$timestamp'},
          'hour':{$hour:'$timestamp'},
          'minute':{$minute:'$timestamp'}}},
    'tweets': { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
}
])
```

Finally, for your comment about large amount of data, latest versions of mongoDB return aggregation results as cursor.

Docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/